Angular - Firebase Push Notification node.js send notification to the device
I have a function called callBackend() that sends notifications. It works perfectly on the web browser and notifications are sent without any issues. However, when I run the same code on an Android device, the notifications are not triggered.
Has anyone experienced a similar issue or knows what could be causing this? Any help would be greatly appreciated!
the error:
Line 1 - Msg: Error sending notification: {"headers":{"normalizedNames":{},"lazyUpdate":null,"headers":{}},"status":0,"statusText":"Unknown Error","url":"http://localhost:3000/notify","ok":false,"name":"HttpErrorResponse","message":"Http failure response for http://localhost:3000/notify: 0 Unknown Error","error":{"isTrusted":true}}
home.page.ts

import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import {
  FirebaseMessaging,
  GetTokenOptions,
} from "@capacitor-firebase/messaging";
import { Capacitor } from "@capacitor/core";
import { IonicModule } from "@ionic/angular";
import { environment } from "src/environments/environment";

import { NotificationService } from '../services/notification.service';


@Component({
  selector: "app-home",
  templateUrl: "home.page.html",
  styleUrls: ["home.page.scss"],
  standalone: true,
  imports: [IonicModule],
})
export class HomePage {
  public token = "";

  constructor(
    private notificationService: NotificationService
  ) {
    FirebaseMessaging.addListener("notificationReceived", (event) => {
      console.log("notificationReceived: ", { event });
    });
    FirebaseMessaging.addListener("notificationActionPerformed", (event) => {
      console.log("notificationActionPerformed: ", { event });
    });
    if (Capacitor.getPlatform() === "web") {
      navigator.serviceWorker.addEventListener("message", (event: any) => {
        console.log("serviceWorker message: ", { event });
        const notification = new Notification(event.data.notification.title, {
          body: event.data.notification.body,
        });
        notification.onclick = (event) => {
          console.log("notification clicked: ", { event });
        };
      });
    }
  }

  public async requestPermissions(): Promise<void> {
    await FirebaseMessaging.requestPermissions();
  }

  public async getToken(): Promise<void> {
    const options: GetTokenOptions = {
      vapidKey: environment.firebase.vapidKey,
    };
    if (Capacitor.getPlatform() === "web") {
      options.serviceWorkerRegistration =
        await navigator.serviceWorker.register("firebase-messaging-sw.js");
    }
    const { token } = await FirebaseMessaging.getToken(options);
    this.token = token;
  }


  public async callBackend() {
    console.log("call backend", this.token);
    
    // Ensure you have the token before making the request
    if (!this.token) {
      console.error("Token not available. Make sure you call getToken() first.");
      return;
    }
  
    const notificationData = {
      token: this.token,  // Include the token in the data
      notification: {
        title: 'Test Notification',
        body: 'This is a test notification'
      },
      data: {
        detailsId: '123'
      }
    };
  
    // Send the request to the backend
    this.notificationService.sendNotification(notificationData).subscribe(
      (response) => {
        console.log('Notification sent successfully:', response);
      },
      (error) => {
        console.error('Error sending notification:', error);
      }
    );
  }


}

index.js:
import express from "express";
import request from "request";
import { google } from "googleapis";
import { readFile } from "fs/promises";

import cors from 'cors';

const app = express();
const port = 3000;

// Use the CORS middleware
app.use(cors());

app.use(express.json());

// Function to get Google Cloud access token
async function getAccessToken() {
  try {
    const key = JSON.parse(await readFile(new URL('./angular-firebase-app-b7d17-firebase-adminsdk-3mx51-041a7cc2e5.json', import.meta.url)));
    const SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform']; 

    const jwtClient = new google.auth.JWT(
      key.client_email,
      null,
      key.private_key,
      SCOPES,
      null
    );

    const tokens = await jwtClient.authorize();
    console.log('Access Token:', tokens.access_token);
    return tokens.access_token;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error retrieving access token:', error);
    throw new Error('Failed to retrieve access token');
  }
}

// Route to send push notification
app.post('/notify', async (req, res) => {
  const { token, notification, data } = req.body;

  if (!token) {
    return res.status(400).json({ error: 'Token is required' });
  }

  console.log('Notification Data:', notification, data);
  console.log('Token:', token);

  try {
    const accessToken = await getAccessToken(); // Get access token

    // Send FCM notification
    const options = {
      method: 'POST',
      url: 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/AppId/messages:send',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`, // Using the Google Cloud access token
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        message: {
          token: token, 
          notification: {
            title: notification.title,
            body: notification.body,
          },
          data: data,
        },
      }),
    };

    request(options, (error, response, body) => {
      if (error) {
        console.error('Error sending push:', error);
        return res.status(500).json({ error: 'Failed to send notification' });
      }

      console.log('Push sent successfully:', body);
      res.json({ success: true, message: 'Notification sent!' });
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error sending notification:', error);
    res.status(500).json({ error: 'Internal Server Error' });
  }
});

// Start server
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Backend running at http://localhost:${port}`);
});


notification.service.ts:
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class NotificationService {
  private apiUrl = 'http://localhost:3000/notify';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  sendNotification(notificationData: any): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post(this.apiUrl, notificationData);
  }
}



Your index.js never returns the actual error message to the client. What output do you get from console.error('Error sending notification:', error);?

I am encountering an error in the home.page.ts file  like this -->
Msg: Error sending notification: {"headers":{"normalizedNames":{},"lazyUpdate":null,"headers":{}},"status":0,"statusText":"Unknown Error","url":"http://localhost:3000/notify","ok":false,"name":"HttpErrorResponse","message":"Http failure response for http://localhost:3000/notify: 0 Unknown Error","error":{"isTrusted":true}}
When I run the application on an Android device, it cannot access the index.js file, which is why no error is being returned from there.

Yup, that's what you said in the question already. My earlier comment is about how to find the actual error message that happens on the server.
